# User forms authentication in JSF

Tags: java, authentication, jsf

I'm a novice at JSF and I got a couple of questions concerning organizing user authentication there.

1) How can i redirect the registered user to a welcome page (for example welcome.xhtml)? I heard about using Filter or navigation-rule tag, but i didn't found a full-blown tutorial of how it works.

2) How can i tell the server that unauthorized users can access not only the login page but also the registration page? Is there an analog for ASP.NET web.config tag  or something like this?

Comment: The answer depends on how exactly you're authenticating your users. Container managed or webapp (homegrown) managed?

Comment: Webapp. 
My task is just to create a sample site in JSF with the ability to register and to log a user in to some "helloworld" page with user data stored in mysql database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for requirement 1) is already achieved by the solution for requirement 2). You just let the user go to that URL directly. If the user is after all not logged in, then redirect them to the register/login page. That's how it normally works.

You need to implement a `Filter` which listens on an `url-pattern` matching the secured pages. E.g. `/secured/*`, `/protected/*`, etc. In the `doFilter()` method you just check for the presence of the logged in `User` in the current session and handle accordingly. Here's a basic kickoff example:

```
if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession().getAttribute("user") == null) {
    // Not logged in, redirect to login page.
    response.sendRedirect("login.jsf");
} else {
    // Logged in, just continue with request.
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

To get it to work with JSF, just know the fact that JSF stores session scoped managed beans as attributes of the `HttpSession` with the managed bean name as key.

Comment: If like me you are looking for a complete `Filter` example have a look to this link : http://thierrywasyl.wordpress.com/2009/06/22/create-your-own-filter-in-jsf. The article demonstrates how to create easily an authentication scenario with JSF.